# RestSharp ExecuteAsync UI not waiting for rest call completion

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, async-await, restsharp, nancy

I have been trying to use download a file from my angular 6 application by calling an API method GetFile() written using NancyFx.

The GetFile() API method again calls a web API method GetRemoteFile() using RestSharp.

The GetFile() method follows the async/await pattern. But I see that the file gets downloaded before the success callback of GetRemoteFile() is even being called.

And because of this the downloaded file is 0 bytes.

```
using RestSharp.Extensions.MonoHttp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using Nancy.Json;
using RestSharp.Extensions;
using System.Net;
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Responses;
using RestSharp;

private async Task<Nancy.Response> GetFile(int orderId)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest($"api/GetRemoteFile", Method.POST);            
            string json = SomeBodyData();
            request.AddJsonBody(new RemoteParameter
            {
                OId = documentId,
                Json = json
            });            
            var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IResponse>();
            client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://someremoteapi.com/orders/");            
            var res = client.PostAsync(request, (response,handle) =>
            {   
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(response);
            });

            var data = await taskCompletionSource.Task;
            var stream = new MemoryStream(data.RawBytes);
            stream.Position = 0;
            var file= new StreamResponse(() => stream, "text/csv");
            return file;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to await the PostAsync e.g. var res = await client.PostAsync(...)

Comment: Yes I tried that too, but it didn't worked too.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the async flow and await `ExecuteTaskAsync`. With that, you should be able get the desired behavior.

```
private async Task<Nancy.Response> GetFile(int orderId) {
    var request = new RestRequest($"api/GetRemoteFile", Method.POST);
    string json = SomeBodyData();
    request.AddJsonBody(new RemoteParameter {
        OId = documentId,
        Json = json
    });        
    client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://someremoteapi.com/orders/");
    var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);

    var stream = new MemoryStream(response.RawBytes);
    stream.Position = 0;
    var file= new StreamResponse(() => stream, "text/csv");
    return file;
}
```

Comment: I tried but this didn't worked. The file still gets downloaded even before the remote api call completes. Also just fyi, the call from UI is a GET call while the remote api call is a POST call.

Comment: Btw I don't see a method ExecuteTaskAsync() instead I  see and have used ExecuteAsync()

Comment: @thinkmmk It is there, check again https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/IRestClient.cs#L196

Comment: @thinkmmk based on your last comment, how can you say this did not work when you did not implement what I suggested.

Comment: I am using .net core and I dont see the method you mentioned. Assembly RestSharp.NetCore, Version=105.2.3.0. So I tried the nearest method which you suggested and it didn't work. Am I missing something here?